# AttributeError: 'Hero' object has no attribute 'image_getrect'

Tags: python, pygame, attributes

So I am learning to code on python with pygame. I am currently following a series of video tutorials for coding games.

I have followed the tutors code to the letter and checked and double checked (to the point of even checking his base code file.

But when I try to run the game I get this error:

File "/home/dev/PycharmProjects/Game5_Catch_Cookie/modules/hero.py", line 16, in **init**
self.rect = self.image_getrect()

so line 16 in the hero class set up code looks like:

```
class Hero(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, images, position=[375, 520], **kwargs):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.images_right = images[:5]
        self.images_left = images[5:]
        self.images = self.images_right.copy()
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.rect = self.image_getrect() <------------- Line 16
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = position
        self.direction = 'right'
        self.speed = 8
        self.switch_frame_count = 0
        self.switch_frame_freq = 1
        self.frame_index =0
```

I'm not sure what to do about this or how to fix it so the game I'm trying to learn to code works properly.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Don't you mean ```self.rect = self.image.get_rect()```?

Comment: yes thank you that fixed at least that problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
self.rect = self.image_getrect()
```

You need to write

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```